# EA-Turbo simulation package

Tags: error-correction, resource-request

I am working with the quantum turbo codes presented in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.1256.pdf) by Wilde, Hsieh and Babar, and it is claimed that a package to simulate such codes is available at [ea-turbo](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ea-turbo/). However, the hyperlink to such package appears to be broken, and so I have not been able to reach that.

I would like to know if anyone around knows another link to get such package, or it by any chance has the package, if he could share it so that other people can work with such codes in an easier way.

**EDIT:**

It looks like a package containing the version used by the authors for a previous [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6034165/) on the topic where a simpler decoder is used can be downloaded from the link presented in the answer by user1271772. I discovered such fact by reading the README file that such file contains. It would be very useful to know if newer versions (looks like the broken link that I was talking about in the questions refers to a second version of the package) can be obtained too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hyperlink works for me: https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/ea-turbo/ea-turbo.zip

That is a zip file which I was able to download.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helpful. However, I have gone through the file and found out that the version that is contained in such zip file is an older version from a previous paper. I will edit the question to specify such fact. Anyway it is very helpful the information that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question has been edited, there is a slightly different answer to the question (though my previous answer still has a valid link, so I am keeping it there).

The broken link presumably refers to:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B77vaqbQKbrDMWEtTUxyZDgwanc/ea-turbo-v2.zip

Which is the link at the bottom of:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/ea-turbo/

The solution to the problem (broken link) is to contact the authors: Mark M. Wilde, Min-Hsiu Hsieh, and Zunaira Babar.

I agree with you that ideally questions like these could just be answered here on the QCSE, but I am almost 100% sure that the only three people that will be able to fix the broken link are Mark M. Wilde, Min-Hsiu Hsieh, and Zunaira Babar, and I'm 0% sure that they will see the question if it's asked here.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I might try to edit the code to implement such decoder, and otherwise I will try to contact the authors. I will check as the valid answer the first answer that you gave as it gives the download to at least one of the versions of the package.